# gerneric handler for non handled error with angular

Tags: angular

I want to create generic error handler for server side and client also. I faced an issue; when the method does catch the error i don't want to catch it again. I use ErrorHandler for handle global event, i would use it also for http calls errors but it does not handle the asynchronous calls in fact it waits to do an action and then to handle the error. So i use HttpInterceptor for that and the issue here it catchs already the catched errors hence the message is displayed twice.

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private readonly injector: Injector) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            retry(1),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                const errorService = this.injector.get(ErrorService);
                const exceptionHandlerService = this.injector.get(ExceptionHandlerService);
                let errorMessage = '';

                // server-side error
                errorMessage = errorService.getServerMessage(error);
                exceptionHandlerService.handleError(error, 'server side', errorMessage);

                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    handleError(error): void {
            let message: string;
            const errorService = this.injector.get(ErrorService);
            const exceptionHandlerService = this.injector.get(ExceptionHandlerService);

            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                // Client Error
                message = errorService.getClientMessage(error);
                exceptionHandlerService.handleError(error, 'client handler', message);
            }
    }
}
```

```
 providers: [
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ServerErrorInterceptor, multi: true
        },
]
```

Comment: If you don’t want to handle caught errors, then don’t rethrow then. return EMPTY or something in that case

Comment: If i return for example new Observable<HttpEvent<any>>() it will ignore the caught already done in the catch section in the method. And want the interceptor to not handle error if is already catched. The ErrorHandler can do that but with method HttpInterceptor does not containt subscription to observable; So how i can i tell the  HttpInterceptor to stop when error is already handled or how to force the ErrorHandler to not handle error without waiting